# MySQL/iBatis :- Inserted data in the database table gets deleted automatically

Tags: mysql, database, ibatis

I am inserting some data in the database table through my web application, here the row gets generated for example with id - 466 in the database table but then it automatically gets deleted when I check my database table.When i try to insert the data using same query through MySQL workbench the data gets inserted successfully with id - 467 this time. Any kind of help would be appereciated thank you.

I have written a query to insert data in mysql database :-

```
 <insert id="addCommunication" parameterType="map"
    useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
    insert into t_communications
    (sid,

    <if test="puserid != null and puserid != ''">puserid,</if>
    <if test="groupid != null and groupid != ''">groupid,</if>

    note,lastupdated,commdatetime,tuserid)
    values
    (#{sid},

    <if test="puserid != null and puserid != ''">
        #{puserid},
    </if>
    <if test="groupid != null and groupid != ''">
        #{groupid},
    </if>
    #{note},
    #{currenttimestamp},
    #{commdatetime},
    #{tuserid}
    );
    <selectKey resultType="string" order="AFTER" keyProperty="id">
        SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as returnedId
    </selectKey>
</insert>
```

Comment: please ask it with proper details.this is not a clear question.

Comment: @ Sachith i have written the query above...the data gets inserted but gets deleted automatically from the database.Is there some problem with mysql database or what ?Please let me know if u need further details.Thank you.

Comment: What data source are you using? Can you post your data source configuration?